# How can i get an input of 3 double variables with cin in C++?

Tags: c++, input, output, double, cin

I must take 3 double variables as an input and find their mean. If i input a integer as a input(for example 5) program works. but if i input a fractional number(for example 5.3) it wont take the other 2 inputs and close.

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   double y1,y2,y3,ort; 
   cout<<"1. input : \n";
   cin>>y1;
   cout<<"2. input : \n"; 
   cin>>y2;
   cout<<"3. input : \n";
   cin>>y3;
   ort=(y1+y2+y3)/3;
   cout<<"Value : "<< ort << "\n" ; 
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce https://wandbox.org/permlink/Tz9JXlcuo8qRKLi1

Comment: Works for me too: [https://ideone.com/QUJaQb](https://ideone.com/QUJaQb)

Comment: Do you perhaps have your locale set to use a comma decimal rather than a dot?

Comment: Are you sure that is the code you are running? Perhaps you originally wrote the code to take `int` variables and you are still running the old binary.

Comment: how can i write this code to take double variables? i am a newbie in c++.

Comment: if you input 3 its working. but if you input 3,2 its not working.

Comment: In C++ fractional numbers are by default written with `.` not `,`. You can change it, but I don't think it something worth doing for a beginner. Just try `3.2` instead of `3,2`.

Comment: ***how can i write this code to take double variables?*** You already did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program works as expected. At least the mean is computed accordingly, the `pause` call is not working for me.

```
1. input : 
1.3
2. input : 
2.3
3. input : 
3.3
Value : 2.3
sh: 1: pause: not found
Press <RETURN> to close this window...
```

Maybe you have wrong locale set.

You can try add:

```
#include <locale.h> 
setlocale(LC_ALL,"C")
```

As I just read your comment `if you input 3 its working. but if you input 3,2 its not working.`, floating points are by programming standards separated with `.`, not `,`. E.g. you have to write `3.2`. That is what English speaking countries have also in their standard.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is corect. 
I think you wrote in input 5,3. When you use sign , your program run incorrect.
You shouldn't use system("pause").